# Order two meged queries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union

I have `Customers` table and I want to pull out shortest and longest customer name

I do it like this:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName, LEN(CustomerName) AS LENGTH FROM Customers ORDER BY LEN(CustomerName) ASC, CustomerName ASC)
UNION
(SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName, LEN(CustomerName) AS LENGTH FROM Customers ORDER BY LEN(CustomerName) DESC, CustomerName ASC)
```

I get two correct results but now I want to sort them by `LENGTH` column. I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
(SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName, LEN(CustomerName) AS LENGTH FROM Customers ORDER BY LEN(CustomerName) ASC, CustomerName ASC)
UNION
(SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName, LEN(CustomerName) AS LENGTH FROM Customers ORDER BY LEN(CustomerName) DESC, CustomerName ASC)
)
ORDER BY LEN(CustomerName) ASC
```

But it gives me this error: `Syntax error in JOIN operation.`

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't even see a `JOIN` in the source you shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select customername,len(customername) as namelength
from (SELECT MAX(LEN(CustomerName)) AS MAXLENGTH, MIN(LEN(CustomerName)) AS MINLENGTH 
      FROM Customers) lens
join customers c on c.len(customername) = lens.maxlength or c.len(customername) = lens.minlength
order by namelength desc, customername
```